# Having trouble displaying static files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

I cannot figure out what if any url thing I am supposed to add to my urls.py file to be able to display static files. I have tried adding the following as I have seen that it worked for others on stack overflow

`url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),`

`url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),`

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

none of which seem to work.

I seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include static in the urls.py file. In your settings.py you have to specify directory with static files and url:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: is that the only place I have to specify the URL? because I am still having trouble displaying static files on /admin pages and other pages (all of my pages).

Comment: Yes, it's only place to specify URL. Also, when you're in production you must run 'python manage.py collectstatic' command that will copy all static content from your app to path specified in STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: Although useful information for me to remember I am still having a problem displaying my static files.

Comment: This isn't happening with any template in particular, it is happening with all of my templates including the default admin pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try Running,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and try again you don't need to add anything in urls add

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in setting.py

create a folder named static in your app directory

place your static files inside that directory

use for eg `<img src="{% static '<path from static directory>' %}" />`

don't forget to include `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template

Comment: `<path to your file from>` is the path to my file from within `/static/` right?

Comment: I thought it would have fixed it since I had neglected to add the tag `{% load staticfiles %}` but it didnt and I am still unable to display static files.

Comment: did you added the app in the settings.py file in Installed apps

Comment: yes, I did, my static files for admin dont work either though

Comment: were you are trying this? , in your local or in production

Comment: I was trying this in production

Comment: Is your static files were working properly in local..?
check this for how to serve static files in production
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-media-files